# How do I prevent ajax DataTables from triggering after every keystroke?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a DataTable that is created on page load. It's searchable and has the following initialization:

```
   $('#empTable').DataTable({
      'processing':true,
      'serverSide': true,
      'serverMethod': 'post',
      'ajax': {
          'url':'remote-file.php'
      },
      'columns': [
         { data: 'name' },
         { data: 'date' },
         { data: 'field' },
         { data: 'old_value' },
         { data: 'new_value' },
         { data: 'changed_by' }
      ]
   });
```

This seems to trigger a call to the url on every keystroke in the search box on the DataTable.

How can I make it kill the previous ajax call or at least wait 200 or so milliseconds after they finish typing to trigger the ajax call?

Comment: There is a [`searchDelay`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/searchDelay) option - I think that does what you need. It does say that the default is already 400ms - so if you are seeing something different (i.e. faster), then that needs a closer look.

Comment: Maybe this link helps you: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/46574/how-to-set-a-different-timeout

Comment: @andrewjames this seems to create a delay between each call, but still triggers numerous calls to the remote file (which takes 3-5 seconds to run), therefore it creates a long list of calls if I type a handful of characters. Is there a way to do an abort() on the ajax call if it's called again?

Comment: OK, I see. Not sure about using an abort, but for a delay of that length, I would say perhaps you need an explicit "submit" button to let the user control when they have finished typing. Sorry, I don't have a better approach!